# Multiple process for selecting data in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Please help me, I have the table of postgresql like this:

```
tbl_user
----------------------------------
id          name        is_checked
----------------------------------
1           data1       0
2           data2       0
3           data3       0
4           data4       0
5           data5       0
6           data6       0
7           data7       0
8           data8       0
9           data9       0
10          data10      0
----------------------------------
```

In php I have many users login. 
When they get data for checking, 
they will see data in difference 
because I want them to update field is_checked="1" for difference data by user:

```
- user 1:
    select * from tbl_user limit 2;
    => result:
        1           data1       0
        2           data2       0

- user 2:
    select * from tbl_user limit 2;
    => result:
        3           data3       0
        4           data4       0

- user 3:
    select * from tbl_user limit 2;
    => result:
        5           data5       0
        6           data6       0
------------------
```

I want user check data without duplicate row. if one row is checking by one user, then other users not be able to see that row.
Please help to give me the solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 values for the `is_checked` field, for example:

0 means “up for grabs”
1 means “is being checked”
2 means “is checked”

Then every worker selects the values like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_user t
SET is_checked = 1
FROM (SELECT t1.id
      FROM tbl_usr t1
      WHERE t1.is_checked = 0
      LIMIT 2
      FOR UPDATE) t2
WHERE t.id = t2.id
RETURNING t.*;
```

When checking is completed, `is_checked` is updated to 2.

Instead of `integer` you might want to use an enumeration data type for `is_checked`.